# What might be an equivalent to Linux /opt/ in OpenBSD?

Tags: linux, openbsd, directory-structure

In OpenBSD there is no `/opt/`, as there is with Linux.

From `man hier` in Ubuntu Server 18.04:

> **/opt** This  directory  should  contain  add-on  packages  that contain static files.

What would be a suitable equivalent in OpenBSD?

Comment: What do you see as an issue with using `/opt` on OpenBSD? It's not mentioned by the `hier(7)` manual on OpenBSD, which means it will be out of the way of the system.

Comment: I needed to understand the mount settings for `/opt`, because `/usr/local` is the only partition mounted with `wxallowed`. I realize this can be a project-by-project issue to resolve with maintainers, but if `/opt` is generally assumed to be freely interchangeable with `/usr/local`, then it should be created using the same mount settings, however that choice is made (e.g., symlink, attached block storage, etc.). As it happens, I found a completely different way around this problem, so did not need to resolve the issue, but I will leave the question because search results on this were weak.

Answer (score 1):

Even in linux, /opt is frequently empty.

You could just create /opt or you could use /usr/local

Comment: To create `/opt` means figuring out the `mount` options for the new partition, then repartitioning. In Openbsd `man hier`: `/usr/ Contains the majority of user utilities and applications.` and `/usr/local/ Local executables, libraries, etc.`. I am looking at installing Wildfly, and every guide I can find is for Linux and states to install to `/opt/` and Linux also has in `man hier`: `/usr/local This is where programs which are local to the site typically go.`

Comment: /opt isn't that special.  It's just a directory.   You don't have to "mount" it to create it.  Pick a disk that has space and create opt and symlink to /opt if you want.   Or if / has enough space, just create it there.

Comment: Have you much experience with OpenBSD?

Comment: Using `/usr/local` is not a good idea if you also install packages using `pkg_add`.  Just use `/opt`.  It's not used by anything on an OpenBSD system and is therefore safe.  Note that whatever Linux says about its file system hierarchy is irrelevant for non-Linux systems.

Comment: BSD used /opt and /usr/local decades before linux existed.   If pkg_add would collide with `/usr/local/$pkgname` then that is unfortunate, I would expect it more likely it would collide with `/opt/$pkgname`.  And as far as I know, you don't need to mount a partition to create a directory in `/`.